# Get an array of N values(that are not present at "exclude" array) from an array X scanning in reverse and mutate the X array removing the added items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array named `queue` which will have some finite values in it. I want at max 2 records in the `result` array from the `queue` *"scanning from the last index"* where the values that are to be added `result` should not exist in the `exclude` array.

**In short the conditions are:**

- The `queue` array needs to be scanned from right to left direction.
- If the value scanned is not found in the `exclude` array, the value should be added to the `result` array.
- When the `result` array thus obtained will have the length of maximum size N or when the end of the `queue` array is reached, the process should be terminated.
- The `queue` array should be mutated in this process i.e. after adding the value to the `result`, the value should removed from the `queue` array(or can be removed at last it doesn't matter but it should be observed when the process terminates).

For an example:

```js
let queue = [7, 9, 3, 4, 5];
let exclude = [4, 6, 10];
let resultCount = 2; // result's maximum length
let result = []; // will contain the result values
```

**The expected end result looks like this:**

```js
result = [5, 3]; // can be in any order
queue = [7, 9, 4]; // mutated queue
```

Here, scanning from the last index, the value `5` is found unique and added to the `result` array but value `4` is skipped because it exists on the `exclude` array. Then the value `3` is found unique and added to the `result` array. Since the maximum size of the `result` array, 2 is reached i.e. `[5, 3]`, the process is terminated. The matching values will also be removed from the `queue` array leaving the array `[7, 9, 4]` at the end of the process.

Is there any way achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `while` loop and looping through your `queue` backwars until either you reach the `0th` index or you reach your `resultsCount`, you can check whether each `queue` element is in your `exclude` array. If it isn't, you can add this element to your `result` array using `.push()`, and then remove it from the `queue` using `.splice(index, 1)`.

See example below:

```js
let queue = [7, 9, 3, 4, 5];
let exclude = [4, 6, 10];
let resultCount = 2; // result's maximum length
let result = []; // will contain the result values

let i = queue.length-1; // get last index in queue
while(result.length < resultCount && i >= 0) { // keep looping your queue array until you either reach your resultsCount or you get to index -1 
  const curr = queue[i]; // get the current queue item
  if(!exclude.includes(curr)) { // if the current item is not inside your exclude array...
    result.push(curr); // push the current element into the resulting array
    queue.splice(i, 1); // remove it from the queue
  }
  i--; // decrement i
}
console.log(result);
console.log(queue);
```

You can also use a `Set` for your exclude array if you have many elements in it to help with efficiency.

Using `.filter()` can also be nice, but it creates new arrays rather than modifying in-place:

```js
let queue = [7, 9, 3, 4, 5];
const exclude = new Set([4, 6, 10]);
const resultCount = 2; // result's maximum length

const result = queue.filter(n => !exclude.has(n)).slice(resultCount);
queue = queue.filter(n => !result.includes(n));
console.log(result);
console.log(queue);
```

Comment: Wow, the higher order function implementation is much convenient. Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to step backwards through an array with a for loop.

```js
let queue = [7, 9, 3, 4, 5];
let exclude = [4, 6, 10];
let resultCount = 2; // result's maximum length
let result = []; // will contain the result values

// Step backwards through the array
for(let i = queue.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  // If the number is not in the exclude list
  if(!exclude.includes(queue[i])){
    // Add to the array
    result.push(queue[i])
    // Remove from queue array.
    queue.splice(i, 1);
  }
  if(result.length >= resultCount) {
    // End the for loop
    break;
  }
}

console.log(queue);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: No problem, looks like the logic in my solution is much the same as the other post by Nick :)

Comment: Yes, Nick's and your answer's key difference is the loop. I found your `for` loop appropriate though. Will be using it